# SQLALchemy: How to get all values in a colums?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In Image1 the table is named T_File in Postgresql, and it has GroupID column, as you can see it is 3632, corresponding with GroupID column is FileID column (is the number of pages of template so template in GroupID 3632 has 5 pages => FileID from 1-5).

The image below is my code. So I want the output in my list will be :

```
grup_id : [3632, 3632, 3632, 3632, 3632, 3633, 3634, 3635, 3636]
```

Correspond with the FileID in another list will be :

```
[1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5, 1, 1, 2 ..etc.]
```

And the width , Height will be correspond with FileID [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

As you can see in the output terminal it still contains only one 3632 and the rest 4 of it doesn't appear, and the `file_id` is just 1. I need `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as in the `FileID in postgresql`.

Thank you all for your help, I'm pretty new to SQLALchemy

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In the `T_File` object I miss the `primary_key = True`, added it and the code run as I expected